# Get a open Dialog without having any references to it

Tags: android, android-dialog

On Android, if I added a Dialog into the screen and another Activity opens, how can I get from that Activity all the open Dialogs?

I need to close one of them.

Comment: what do you mean?! the dialogs belong to the context of the previous activity how can you close them? the way to do so (logically) would return a result to the previous activity that tells it to close one of the dialogs... I am assuming the other Activity is opened using startActivityForResult

Comment: It's opened with startActivity only.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class and extend `DialogFragment` and in `onCreateDialog`return your dialog, then show this dialog fragment with a specific tag , after that , you can find this dialog by using `activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("the tag")`.

Don't hold a reference to your dialog (local or global) because the activity can get recreated and it will leak the reference in the memory, just get the reference with the findFragment method.

If you are in a fragment , you can use `fragment.getChildFragmentManager(...)` and do the same.
Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

When another activity opens, your current activity will go through the onPause() state. More info on it can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

In the onPause() call dialog.dismiss() and you should be set.

Comment: But how I'll get this dialog to dismiss it?

Comment: you will have to keep a global reference to the open dialogs!